# SignalR code not getting invoked for request handling

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I need to Cancel the sent request when the Cancel button is clicked. Unfortunately, as of now the sent request is not getting cancelled. My use case is that once the User clicks on the Cancel button, a PopUp appears and then if the User clicks on Cancel Request then, Friend Request should be cancelled else if the user clicks on Do not cancel the request, the friend request should remain intact. I am using SignalR for Sending requests

**Following is my code for the same:**

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.InviteNurse = function (NurseId, Type) {
    var NurseFriendId = $("#connect_" + NurseId).attr("NurseFriendId");
    alert(Type);
    if ($scope.CurrentUser) {

        if (Type != 3)
        {
            var RequestObject = {
                NurseId: NurseId,
                FNurseId: $scope.CurrentUser.NurseId,
                Type: Type,
                NurseFriendId: NurseFriendId
            }
            signalR.InviteNurse(RequestObject);

            if (RequestObject) {
                RequestObject.InvitedBy = $scope.CurrentUser.NurseId;
                RequestObject.NurseId = NurseId;
            }
        }


 //==============================================Updating Local Buttons for ShowAlert========================================//

        if(Type == 1)
        {
            UserService.showAlert('Your Invitation to Connect has been sent', 1);
        }
        if(Type == 3)
        {
            $('#confirm').modal('show');
        }
        if (Type == 2)
        {
            UserService.showAlert('You have Accepted the Invitation to Connect', 3);
        }
    }
}

$scope.RequestCancel = function () {



    $('#confirm').modal('hide');
    UserService.showAlert('You have Cancelled the Invitation to Connect!', 0);
}


$scope.Cancel = function () {
    $('#confirm').modal('hide');
    UserService.showAlert('You clicked on Do Not Cancel Invite!', 2);
}

$scope.InitType = function (NurseId, Type) {

    switch (Type) {
        case 0:
            $("#cancel_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#connect_" + NurseId).show();
            $("#accept_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#reject_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#message_" + NurseId).hide();
            break;

        case 1:
            $("#cancel_" + NurseId).show();
            $("#connect_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#accept_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#reject_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#message_" + NurseId).hide();

            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            $("#cancel_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#connect_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#accept_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#reject_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#message_" + NurseId).show();
            break;
        case 4:
            $("#cancel_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#connect_" + NurseId).hide();
            $("#accept_" + NurseId).html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>').show();
            $("#reject_" + NurseId).html('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>').show();
            $("#message_" + NurseId).hide();

    }
}
```

Following is the code for **ChatHub.cs:**

```
public void InviteNurse(NurseFriend objNurseFriend)
    {
        Result res = null;
        //if (res.Status == true)
        {

            var InvitedTo = objConnectedUserList.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                   (x.NurseId == objNurseFriend.NurseId)

                   );


            switch (objNurseFriend.Type)
            {
                case "1":
                    res = objMessagingDAL.InsertFriendRequest(objNurseFriend);
                    var fromRequestObject = new
                    {
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 1,
                        NurseFriendId = res.Results
                    };

                    var toRequestObject = new
                    {
                        //FNurseName = InvitedBy.NurseName,
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 4,
                        NurseFriendId = res.Results
                    };

                    if (InvitedTo != null)
                    {
                        Clients.Client(InvitedTo.ConnectionId).notifyUser(toRequestObject);
                        Clients.Client(InvitedTo.ConnectionId).toAcceptRejectRequest(toRequestObject);
                    }
                    Clients.Caller.fromAcceptRejectRequest(fromRequestObject);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    var fromRequestObject1 = new
                    {
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 3
                    };

                    var toRequestObject1 = new
                    {
                        //FNurseName = InvitedBy.NurseName,
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 2
                    };
                    objNurseFriend.IsAccepted = true;
                    res = objMessagingDAL.UpdateFriendRequest(objNurseFriend);
                    if (InvitedTo != null)
                    {
                        Clients.Client(InvitedTo.ConnectionId).notifyUser(toRequestObject1);
                        Clients.Client(InvitedTo.ConnectionId).toAcceptRejectRequest(toRequestObject1);
                    }
                    Clients.Caller.fromAcceptRejectRequest(fromRequestObject1);

                    break;
                case "3":
                    var fromRequestObject2 = new
                    {
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 0
                    };

                    var toRequestObject2 = new
                    {
                        //FNurseName = InvitedBy.NurseName,
                        FNurseId = objNurseFriend.FNurseId,
                        ToNurseId = objNurseFriend.NurseId,
                        Type = 0
                    };
                    res = objMessagingDAL.DeleteFriendRequest(objNurseFriend);
                    if (InvitedTo != null)
                    {
                        Clients.Client(InvitedTo.ConnectionId).toAcceptRejectRequest(toRequestObject2);
                    }
                    Clients.Caller.fromAcceptRejectRequest(fromRequestObject2);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am calling the code from **HTML:**

```
<div class="peoplemain-container" ng-controller="connectCtrl">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="people_container">
        <div class="connect_profile"><img src="@(item.ProfileUrl== ""  ?"/image/placeholder.jpg" : @item.ProfileUrl)" title="@item.Title&nbsp;@item.FirstName&nbsp;@item.LastName" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="job_box">
            <p><b>@item.Title&nbsp;@item.FirstName&nbsp;@item.LastName</b></p>
            <p><span>@item.Profession</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="job_box_btn">
            <button class="details_btn">
                @Html.ActionLink("View Nurse", "NurseView", "Nurse", new { NurseId = item.NurseId }, new { @class = "" })
            </button>

            <button class="details_btn">
                <a style="display:@(item.Status==0? "block": "none")" id="connect_@item.NurseId" NurseFriendId="@item.NurseFriendId" ng-click="InviteNurse(@item.NurseId, 1)">Connect</a>
                <a style="display:@(item.Status==1? "block": "none")" id="cancel_@item.NurseId" NurseFriendId="@item.NurseFriendId" ng-click="InviteNurse(@item.NurseId,3)">Cancel</a>
                <a style="display:@(item.Status==2 || item.Status==3? "block": "none")" id="message_@item.NurseId" NurseFriendId="@item.NurseFriendId" href="/Nurse/GetInbox?FromNurseId=@NurseOneStop.WebSite.Models.ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.NurseId&ToNurseId=@item.NurseId">Message</a>
                <a style="display:@(item.Status==4? "block": "none")" id="accept_@item.NurseId" NurseFriendId="@item.NurseFriendId" ng-click="InviteNurse(@item.NurseId,2);"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
                <a style="display:@(item.Status==4? "block": "none")" id="reject_@item.NurseId" NurseFriendId="@item.NurseFriendId" ng-click="InviteNurse(@item.NurseId,3);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

}
</style>
<!--Confirm Modal -->
<div id="confirm" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cancel the Invitation to Connect</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <h2>Are you sure you want to Cancel the Invitation to Connect</h2>


                    <input type="button" class="btn" ng-click="RequestCancel()" value="CANCEL INVITE">
                    <input type="button" class="btn" ng-click="Cancel()" value="DO NOT CANCEL INVITE">


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On click of the cancel button you need to hit the SignalR Server code and then call the cancel function of the targeted user. I do not see a code block where you are calling the targeted user's Cancel method. Can you check on that

Comment: @Rajshekar the targeted User's cancel method is being called from the ChatHub.cs page where it works just fine without issues. It is only after Modal popup has been added that it has started causing issues. Case 3 is of Deleting the Friend Request which has been sent to a User and only once the Invited User or the Invitee cancels the request, the popup appears asking for confirmation.